# Dictionary of classes without instantiating

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to call class methods that do certain operations(stored in a dictionary of classes) based on the selection made by a user from the main menu.

```
def setup_task(user_input, id):
   #Object
   task_data =  TaskData(id)
   task_steps = tasks(user_input, task_data)
   task_steps()


def tasks(user_input,  task_data):
"""
Maps user input/task type to methods
"""
    tasks = {
        "TaskRed": Red(task_data).setup_red_specific_task,
        "TaskYellow": Yellow(task_data).setup_yellow_specific_task
    }
    return tasks.get(user_input)
```

Here's how the class looks :

```
class TaskRed(BaseClass):
    def  __init__(self, task_data):
    super().__init__()
    #  Used by multiple methods
    self.task_data = task_data

    def setup_red_specific_task(self):
       print("Does something")
```

This works as expected . However, I want to avoid instantiating all the classes in the dictionary in the `tasks` function once at the beginning. I want to do just the one that's needed based on user_input. How do I avoid instantiating the class for all tasks at the beginning?

Saving `"Red(task_data).setup_red_specific_task"` as a string and using eval when I call the method works, however I want to avoid doing that.

Comment: `lambda: Red(task_data).setup_red_specific_task()`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of it is to return a function instance, and have it executed while you are retrieving the value as below:-

```
def tasks(user_input,  task_data):
"""
Maps user input/task type to methods
"""
    tasks = {
        "TaskRed": lambda: Red(task_data).setup_red_specific_task,
        "TaskYellow": lambda: Yellow(task_data).setup_yellow_specific_task
    }
    return tasks.get(user_input)()
```

To explain this I have written the below example:-

```
>>> tasks = {"a": lambda: print("23"), "b": lambda: print("34")}

>>> tasks["a"]
<function <lambda> at 0x7fe21fad45e0>

>>> tasks["a"]()
23
```

If you see above if we printed `tasks["a"]`, it only gave us the function instance and didn't actually execute it. But when we passed "()" in the last, it actually executed the function and gave us the result.